# Upgrading 2-wire to Ecebee3

Tags: thermostat

[image]I have a honeywell 2 wire thermostat (old) that has 2 wires R W that seem to be wired directly to the furnace (blower/burner??) but I  also have a control board with no wires attached to it. I tried wiring my ecobee to it but no power was received. DO I need to jumper something for power to the control board... remove the wires from furnace and connect to control board????

Comment: Your question is unclear. I understand that you have 2 wires from the old thermostat. Are there any other wires present, but not connected?

Comment: You need to run a new thermostat cable run between the furnace and the thermostat location, 5+wires. If that is not doable, will a new stat location work that you can get a multi conductor to.

Answer (score 1):

The Beckett GeniSys™ Advanced Burner Control is used to control the operation of the furnace, and does not appear to supply an external `C` terminal.  However, you *may* be able to power the Ecobee using an additional 24Vac transformer.

If you have an A/C system that the Ecobee is controlling, you can power the Ecobee using the transformer in the A/C system.  Just connect the `R` wire from the A/C to `Rc`, and run a `C` wire from the A/C to the `C` terminal on the Ecobee.

If you're not controlling an A/C system, you'll have to use an external transformer (or if there's one in the furnace).  If there's a transformer in the furnace (in the control box with the `CYGR` terminals), then you should be able to use that (assuming it's connected to power on the primary side).  Simply run a (new or additional) thermostat cable from the furnace up to the thermostat. Then wire it as follows:

- Remove any jumpers between `R` and `Rc` on the Ecobee.
- Connect a wire from the `R` terminal on the control box in the furnace, to the `Rc` terminal on the Ecobee.
- Connect a wire from the `C` terminal on the control box in the furnace, to the `C` terminal on the Ecobee.

Assuming the transformer in the furnace is powered, that should get you up and running.

> ***WARNING:*** Ecobee is an expensive piece of equipment, make sure you verify proper input voltages. You may also want to contact Ecobee support, to verify this is an accepted installation method.